# In Node.js, how do I turn a string to a json?

Tags: javascript, json, http, node.js

For example, a HTTP REST API just returned me a JSON, but of course it's a string right now. How can I turn it into a JSON?

Comment: If you have fixed your problem please accept one of the answers below. If not, let us know whats wrong and we can try to help.

Comment: It's not called "a JSON." JSON is a string format. You want to turn a JSON-formatted string into a JavaScript object. Read this for more details: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 353, accepted):

You need to use this function.

```
JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

And it will return the object / array that was contained within the string.

Comment: I'm doing this on ES6 and it always returns a string.

Answer (score 49):

use the JSON function >

```
JSON.parse(theString)
```