# string to array - javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am reading the plain text file in `node.js` using ajax call from client side.

**Result :**
   `success gives the result as below.`

```
 ""[{\"x\":233,\"y\":279,\"count\":1},{\"x\":256,\"y\":243,\"count\":6}]\n[{\"x\":233,\"y\":279,\"count\":1},{\"x\":256,\"y\":243,\"count\":6}]\n""
```

**After parsing the above result :**

```
   JSON.parse(result);

  "[{"x":233,"y":279,"count":1},{"x":256,"y":243,"count":6}] [{"x":233,"y":279,"count":1},{"x":256,"y":243,"count":6}] "
```

I want to change this string to array of objects,

**Expected Result is array of objects:**

```
   [{"x":233,"y":279,"count":1},{"x":256,"y":243,"count":6},
    {"x":233,"y":279,"count":1},{"x":256,"y":243,"count":6}
   ]
```

**Ajax call Code**

```
$.ajax({
        url: document.URL + "getData",
        method : "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            var info = JSON.parse(result);
            var object = JSON.parse(info);
            console.log(object);

        }
});
```

Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: can you just make the file node.json and just store the json, and use ajax to call it???

Comment: @JeffLee I am working only on retrieval part, No write permission

Comment: @karthick.k, show ajax call

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801699/in-node-js-how-do-i-turn-a-string-to-a-json

Comment: btw var res is not a valid javascript statement????

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QBqZn/      comply error here. how can you parse  it

Comment: @JeffLee I think he has attempted to convert the output of a string constant into a variable declaration and left an extra pair of quotes around the string.

Comment: wow, so you _already_ "double decoded" the output and yet you've _still_ got mangled JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is some seriously messed-up JSON. There's an extra quote mark at each end, and `]\n[` in the middle where there should be a `,`.

You really should fix your server to generate valid JSON, but if you can't, you could tweak it like this:

```
var res = '"[{\"x\":233,\"y\":279,\"count\":1},{\"x\":256,\"y\":243,\"count\":6}]\n[{\"x\":233,\"y\":279,\"count\":1},{\"x\":256,\"y\":243,\"count\":6}]\n"';

var resfix = res.replace( /^"|"$/g, '' ).replace( ']\n[', ',' );

JSON.parse( resfix );
```

I changed the extra set of quotes at the very outside of your `var res =` string to make it a valid JavaScript string for testing.

Comment: that first `var res` line copied from the OP isn't legal.  If the enclosing double quotes aren't really there then the first `.replace()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @karthick.k I don't see how that can work when the `var res` you've supplied isn't even legal JS.

Comment: @Alnitak - good catch, thanks. I'd changed the outermost `"` to `'` in my test case but forgot to copy it over to the answer that way.

Comment: @MichaelGeary it's unclear whether the outer double quotes the OP put in the question ever even existed.

Comment: @Alnitak - True, but the code I posted would work the same with or without them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you've simply got double-encoded JSON.  Just run it through `JSON.parse()` a second time.

**EDIT** actually, that's not quite right - the output contains *two* JS arrays, with a `\n` separator and no enclosing array.  You will have to manipulate the data a bit (looking at that now) to make it parseable a second time.

**EDIT2** This appears to work, albeit that your current `var res` line includes an extra pair of surrounding quotes that aren't legal so in this test I've removed them:

```
var res =  "[{\"x\":233,\"y\":279,\"count\":1},{\"x\":256,\"y\":243,\"count\":6}]\n[{\"x\":233,\"y\":279,\"count\":1},{\"x\":256,\"y\":243,\"count\":6}]\n"

var out = JSON.parse(res.replace(/]\s*\[/g, ','));
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data while second time parsing

Comment: @Swift you're wrong - I did realise it, but the OP wanted the objects from the two arrays to be merged into a _single_ array.