# how to convert text to json in node

Tags: node.js, react-native

```
 User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((user) => {  
    var result = {};
    if (!user) {
       result.message = "Not Found"
       return res.status(404).send(result);
    }
    //check password matches
    if (user.password == req.body.password) {
        user.status = "Success";
        result.message = "Success"
        res.status(200).send(user);
    } else {
        result.message = "Invalid Password";
        res.status(404).send(result);
    }
  })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

How can I convert from text to json the above code. I am checking in postman and it is not accepting the user when checking on text.

Comment: use [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Node.js, how do I turn a string to a json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801699/in-node-js-how-do-i-turn-a-string-to-a-json)

Comment: User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((user) => {  
           var json = 'user',
        obj = JSON.parse(json);
           var result = {};
      if (!obj) {
       result.message = "Not Found"
       return res.status(404).send(result);
      }
    //check password matches
    if (obj.password == req.body.password) {
        user.status = "Success";
        result.message = "Success"
        res.status(200).send(user);
    } 
       })
     i have tried this way but still getting message:not found